# Auto Logon with Test Agent Deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to deploy a test agent to a virtual machine at work in order to run some coded UI tests. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and can get the entire process to work all the way up to the step to configure the test agent on the virtual machine. At this point, it 'times out' as it reboots and attempts to auto logon. Below is the last portion of the log so you can see it for yourself. Any ideas?

```
2016-11-18T03:44:07.9990891Z ##[debug]DistributedTests: PERF: DeployTestAgent: took 7654.5045 ms
2016-11-18T03:44:07.9990891Z ##[debug]DistributedTests: PERF WARNING: DeployTestAgent: took 7654.5045 ms
2016-11-18T03:44:07.9990891Z ##[debug]DistributedTests: configuring testagent process to run with AI-ENGSVCS\Michael.Jenkins
2016-11-18T03:44:07.9990891Z ##[debug]DistributedTests: ConfigureTestAgent powershell script location : C:\TFS\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.25\TestAgentConfiguration.ps1
2016-11-18T03:44:08.0302919Z ##[debug]DistributedTests: Configuring test agent on test machines.
2016-11-18T03:44:08.0458933Z ##[debug]DistributedTests: Total machines where task ConfigureTestAgent needs to be run : 1
2016-11-18T03:44:08.0458933Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'ACTS-DATADEV:5985' is being run
2016-11-18T03:45:08.0644791Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'ACTS-DATADEV:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
2016-11-18T03:46:08.0830649Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'ACTS-DATADEV:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
2016-11-18T03:47:08.1012298Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'ACTS-DATADEV:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
2016-11-18T03:48:08.1186615Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'ACTS-DATADEV:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
2016-11-18T03:49:08.1360932Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'ACTS-DATADEV:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still relevant: I just spend two hours on the same issue, where I had just renamed the computer name of a VM that was working fine yesterday. I configured everything correctly, even added a new Machine Group under Test-Machines, but the VM kept rebooting when it reached the "ConfigureTestAgent" step.

Eventually, I found out that in the "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" step, I forgot to adjust the "Username" for "Agent Configuration". It was 'TEST-AGENT03\Tester', but after renaming the machine, I didn't change it accordingly to 'NEWCOMPUTERNAME\Tester'. I missed this part, because it was set to a seperate environment variable, so it's variable name (in my case, $(ADMIN_USERNAME) ) seemed correctly set when glancing over.

After adjusting the variable to the new computer name, all was working well again.